# using java system property with hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to run a simple hadoop job ,

```
hadoop jar /root/ravi/ConvertDataWithHadoopOne.jar   com.mdotm.recommender.ConvertDataWithHadoopOne -Dmapred.job.priority=VERY_HIGH   /mdotm/observationtotal/2012-11-18 /mdotm/recommendationsworkdir/recommendationinput/2012-11-18
```

However it is taking `-Dmapred.job.priority=VERY_HIGH` as input instead of system property and hence it is failing.

Can anyone please help with what I am doing wrong? T
hanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your hadoop `conf` directory, add the desired JVM args to `hadoop-env.sh`. Something like this should work:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Dmapred.job.priority=VERY_HIGH"
```

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/cluster_setup.html#Configuration+Files

Comment: I want to specify parameter for each command run seperately so i could not specify it in hadoop-env.sh

Comment: It's clunky but you could probably get away with manually (or in your own wrapper script, or however you'd like to do it) setting the `HADOOP_OPTS` environment variable before calling `hadoop`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer One has to use GenericsOptionsParser to handle the arguments if one wants to use system properties.

An example can be found here

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/GenericOptionsParser.html

Comment: If your answer works but mine didn't you should accept your own!